# what is the meaning of this?

Tags: international-travel

It is that when looking for a flight Madrid-Santa Cruz I've found the price and its options, that is correct, but What is the meaning of  SSEEOB, QEEOB, TMEEOB, VEEOB, HEEOB, BEEOB, YOW ? This is always beside the prices

Answer (score 2):

The codes are the different [Fare Basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fare_basis_code) codes available for the flight. The first character of the code is (usually) the [booking class (example for UA)](http://flyerguide.com/index.php/Booking_Classes_(UA)). The different types of fare basis indicate flights with differing flexibility and restrictions, such as requiring so many days advance booking, Saturday night stays and cancellation penalties. In your case, SSEEOB will be the cheapest and most restictive, and YOW will be the most expensive and completely flexible and refundable.